# Vlookup function

Tags: vba, vlookup, lookup, matching, closest

I ve just used Vlookup Function. 
Seems to work fine, but in some cases it doesn't return the very closest value.

Example : If your lookup value is 3.9, it will return 3 instead of 4. Any way to fix that?

Comment: show how your code and data

Comment: Data : I have two columns A and B. For each cell in A, I should find the closest value in B. It's time value (Double values) 

Code :  I was using this line 
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A3"), Range("B3:B13"), 1, True)

Comment: show also data example leading to unwanted result

Comment: 23215.031
23215.294
23215.548
23215.808
23216.068
23216.328
23216.589
23216.848
23217.108
23217.612
23217.63
in the column above, I m looking for the closest value to 23217.
Vlookup gives 23216.848 which is not the closest one. 
23217.108 is the wanted result.

Comment: Please update your question to include these precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MS Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) on VLookUp function, you can set the 4th parameter to "TRUE if you want an approximate match".
In my opinion, the term "approximate" doesnt' mean "closest number", since you can also look up for string or dates.

To solve your problem, create a small function that loop through your data in B column, compare your value in A3 to values in Bx and save the value with the smallest difference.

Comment: Thank you Vincent.

That's what I've done and works perfectly.